# Sonar scanner execution order jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

For my project, we have made the job on Jenkins GUI. Non declarative.
Tasks are :-

1. GIT scm
2. Maven clean install goal
3. Sonar scanner
4. Quality gate
5. War to artifactory

I have defined, sonar scanner in post build steps and deploy to artifactory in post build actions.
Now in console output, order of execution is like war is getting published first and then sonar scanner runs code quality check.
However, i want sonar scanner to execute first.
Can someone please guide me on how i can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Sonar Scanner for maven plugin?
https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven/

You should just be able to add 'sh mvn clean build sonar:sonar' in your Jenkins pipeline and the plugin will do the rest. It will run the unit test, run jacoco if you have it configured, and report it back to sonar.

Comment: Are in different stages? I have build and unit test, sonar scan and quality gate, and push to artifactory as separated stages, so if everything is ok then I have a valid artifact in Artifactory.

Comment: I would leave the build and sonar in the same stage. But you could most certainly move them out to different stages. Quality gate should be its own stage. Make sure you have Jenkins sleep for a min or two while sonar runs it’s checks.